Deploy Helm charts with custom values.yaml with Ansible playbook
I'm trying to deploy ArgoCD Helm chart with a custom values.yaml file, into a Kubernetes cluster using Ansible playbook
This is the code I'm using
- name: Deploy ArgoCD chart inside argocd namespace
  kubernetes.core.helm:
    name: argo
    chart_ref: argo/argo-cd
    release_namespace: argocd
    values_files:
      - /home/user/gitlab/ansible/roles/bootstrap-kubernetes/tasks/values.yaml.j2

In the values.yaml file I added variables placeholders to pass run-time values, like in this case the cluster's name
hostname: {{ variable_hostname }}

However looking into configmaps details I see that the variable placeholder hasn't been replaced by the actual variable value.
hostname: {{ variable_hostname }}

Tried also to put the variable placeholder between quote marks, but with same results.
Is this the right way to do this?

This won't work...
values_files:
  - /home/user/gitlab/ansible/roles/bootstrap-kubernetes/tasks/values.yaml.j2

...because nothing in the documentation for the kubernetes.core.helm module indicates that Ansible applies template processing to the files listed in values_files.
You can use the inline values parameter instead, like this:
- name: Deploy ArgoCD chart inside argocd namespace
  kubernetes.core.helm:
    name: argo
    chart_ref: argo/argo-cd
    release_namespace: argocd
    values:
      hostname: "{{ variable_hostname }}"


It works! Thanks a lot! Only thing to pay attention, is that the variable must be put between quotation marks "{{ variable_hostname }}"

Yes, sorry about that typo. I've corrected the answer. Glad it helped!
